# Sharing AutoFixture across tests

Tags: c#, autofixture

Is sharing the instance of `Fixture` across multiple test methods a good practice?

Or is it better to create a new instance of `Fixture` for every test method?

What is the best practice? It will be good if you can provide me with a source on which one is anti-pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AutoFixture takes its name from the [Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/test%20fixture%20-%20xUnit.html) pattern:

> "a test fixture is all the things we need to have in place in order to run a test and expect a particular outcome. [...] Setting up the test fixture is the first phase of the [Four-Phase Test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Four%20Phase%20Test.html)."

While a [Shared Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Shared%20Fixture.html) is a conceptual possibility, it comes with lots of disadvantages, because it makes it harder to make tests independent of each other.

AutoFixture was explicitly designed to provide a reusable library for creating Fixtures, instead of having to manually code [Fixture Objects](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/03/16/FixtureObject) for every new kind of test context you'd need to create.

There are people who create a single (AutoFixture) `Fixture` object and share it across multiple test methods, but I never understood why they do that; it almost defeats the purpose of AutoFixture.

Still, if you find such a set-up useful, who am I to tell you to stop doing it? Whatever floats your boat... However, AutoFixture was designed with the explicit use case of one `Fixture` instance per test method in mind, and I haven't seen any advantages to doing it the other way.

Answer (score 7):

The *best* practice is to take advantage of [AutoFixture.Xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit) or [AutoFixture.NUnit2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.NUnit2) and avoid creating a `Fixture` instance, inside or outside of the test methods or functions.

If you can't use any of the above Glue Libraries, it is considered a *good* practice when using a *new* instance of the `Fixture` class in each test.

Using a new instance of the `Fixture` class allows you to control how AutoFixture behaves on each particular test, as you may apply Customizations to it, and they are not going to affect all the other tests.